# How to publish new application as apple developer center is down?

Tags: iphone, app-store

The thing is my apple account needs to review and accept new apple agreements. But I cannot find the approval page now. So my app cannot be published. Such a long time since apple developer center is down and I am waiting for more than one week.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

iTunes connect is back up and running so you should be able to get it submitted? If not, you'll just have to wait around. But try iTunes connect

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa

Otherwise, keep an eye on the status site they put up

https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/